# Tengo problema con la instalacion de Netbeans

Tags: netbeans-8.2, ide

Tengo un bugsito jajaja.

Ya Instale Netbeans 8.2, pero en el momento de crear un nuevo proyecto, no me genera, y se queda pensando netbeans, aparte de eso me aparecio el siguiento log

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que me hace falta por configurar, ya desistale netbeans con un programa y lo volvi instalar nuevamente.

Gracias por la ayuda =D

Comment: Qué tal! Esto te servirá https://dominandoweb.com/como-descargar-e-instalar-netbeans/, hay que asegurarnos de tener el JDK previamente instalado.

Comment: Gracias, si no que en mi equipo tenia instalados 2 jdk con la version 9 y 8, el netbeans tomo por defecto el jdk 9 y eso fue que me genero problemas, tuve que cambiar la version de jdk en el archivo netbeans.conf jajaja =P

Comment: Si ese es un error común, hay que tener cuidado con las versiones jejeje! SI ya resolviste tu problema marcarlo como tal!